# How can I get npx create-react-app to stop showing errors

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, rename

I am trying to start a react project using `npx create-react-app dashboard`
It gives this error

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /home/<myfolder>/.npm/_cacache/tmp/33c12b20
npm ERR! dest /home/<myfolder>/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/9c/91/d37284418712530c020c5eb43e204d4f89773a3a9f79c057b3ec241e794e4ddffc99348c00616b947f45b22828a453247f2668c6cb43badfaf4br7dj
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/lilconfig: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/<myfolder>/.npm/_cacache/tmp/33c12b20' -> '/home/i
<myfolder>/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/9c/91/d37284418712530c020c5eb43e204d4f89773a3a9f79c057b3ec241e794e4ddffc99348c00616b947f45b22828a453247f2668c6cb43badfaf4br7dj'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/<myfolder>/.npm/_logs/2022-07-11T04_03_23_264Z-debug-0.log`
```

I use npm `16.15.1` installed with nvm

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try this way :

```
npm init
npm install -g create-react-app
```

after that, create your project :

```
npx create-react-app dashboard
```

Comment: Thanks Paul Mahardika, I did it but it still doesn't work. I think the problem.is from react-scripts, cause I installed react and react-dom separately and they worked, but trying to install react-scripts showed the same error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).